# Access distributed mnesia database from different nodes

Tags: database, erlang, distributed, mnesia

I have a mnesia database containning different tables.

I want to be able to access the tables from different Linux terminals.

I have a function called `add_record`, which takes a few parameters, say `name` and `id`. I want to be able to call `add_record` on `node1` and `add record` on `node2` but I want to be updating the same table from different locations.

I read a few sources and the only thing i found out was that i should use [`net_adm:ping`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html#ping-1) (node2). but somehow I cant access the data from the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i assume that you probably meant `replicated` table. Suppose you have your mnesia table on node: `nodea@127.0.0.1` with `-setcookie mycookie`, whether its replicated on another node or not, if i want to access the records from another terminal, then i have to use erlang in this other terminal as well by creating a node, connecting this node to our node with the table (you ensure that they all have the same cookie), then you call a method on the remote node. 
Lets say you want to use a method `add_record` in module `mydatabase.erl` on the node `nodea@127.0.0.1` which is having the mnesia table, the i open a linux terminal and i enter the following:

```
$ erl -name remote@127.0.0.1 -setcookie mycookie
Eshell V5.8.4  (abort with ^G)
1> N = 'nodea@127.0.0.1'.
'nodea@127.0.0.1'
2> net_adm:ping(N).
pong
3> rpc:call(N,mydatabase,add_record,[RECORD]).
{atomic,ok}
4>
```

with this module (`rpc`), you can call any method on a remote node, if the two nodes are connected using the same cookie. start by calling this method on the remote node:

```
rpc:call('nodea@127.0.0.1',mnesia,info,[]).
```

It should display everything in your remote terminal. I suggest that probably, you first go through this lecture: [Distributed Erlang Programming](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distribunomicon#setting-up-an-erlang-cluster) and then you will be able to see how replicated mnesia tables are managed. Go through that entire tutorial on that domain.